# Android - Issue in receiving JSonObject String having length more than 1000 characters in mobile device

Tags: android, json, wcf

My android app accesses a (.NET) WCF service (deployed at separate machine on IIS7) to retrieve customers' data to show on a mobile device but when JSon string data size increases to 1000 characters, then the exception handler catches it with the error "string terminated with invalid character", which is supposed to be "}]", but due to string truncation, it doesn't find it.

The confusing thing is that it happens only when I execute the app from my mobile device (i.e. Lenovo S960), but works perfectly from Android Studio, so I couldn't find anything by debugging the source code. Initially, I thought it could be a JSon size issue, but I get the full json string when I access same WCF service through the browser (URL) from the client machine, which shows that IIS is returning full data.

My question is this: why is only the mobile device (production environment) unable to get the JSon string having more than 1000 characters? Following is the code which consumes data from the WCF for your reference.

```
private synchronized static boolean getRawXML(String URL,
        SerializedObject responseOut,ErrMsgOut errMsgOut) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity.getContentLength() != 0) {
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
            char[] buffer = new char[(int) response.getEntity().getContentLength()];
            reader.read(buffer);
            reader.close();

            responseOut.setResponse(new String(buffer));
        }
        else {
            errMsgOut.setErrorDescription("Unable to get raw data!");
            return false;
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        errMsgOut.setErrorDescription("getRawXML( )\n" + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: your `InputStreamReader` should read the data in a `while` loop

Comment: What do you mean it works from Android Studio?  The debug app works and the production app doesn't?

Comment: I meant when i run this App from Android studio by using emulator it consumes full data from the web service which is deployed on another machine no matter JSon string size is greater than 1000 characters but from different mobile devices same app is not able to receive JSON string data beyond 1000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

> i get full json string when I access same WCF service thru (URL) browser from client machine which shows that IIS is returning full data.

Check the content length header coming back from the server.  IIRC, you really can't count on the content length being exactly the length of the data returned because of things like compression and chunked response data.

Also, instead of trying to divine the buffer size, reading the output stream into a string and processing the string, just process the output stream.  Check out `android.util.JsonReader` for a way to do that.  It's better on memory usage that way as well.